Existence of prime numbers close to given integers
Given an integer $n$, let $p(n)$ denote the largest prime that is less than or equal to $n$.
I am looking for an upper bound on the distance $n-p(n)$, or on the ratio $n/p(n)$. For example, is there a theorem such as "$n-p(n)<\log(n)$ for all $n$", or "$n/p(n) < 2$ for all $n$", or anything similar to this?

This is essentially the same question as asking about prime gaps, where a lot is known (and a lot is still yet to be proved).

@GregMartin I read this page, it contains a lot of theorems, but I could not find one that answers my question.

For example, Bertrand's postulate says that the next prime after $p(n)$ is at most $2p(n)$. Therefore $n-p(n) < n$ and $n/p(n) < 2$ (since $n$ is smaller than the next prime after $p(n)$).

@GregMartin Thanks! In the web page on Bertrand's postulate I found many results on the same kind. For example, Jitsuro Nagura proved that, for all $n\geq 25$, there is a prime between $n$ and $1.2n$. Therefore, $n/p(n)<6/5$

The above $n/p(n) < 2$ actually implies slightly better bound $n-p(n)<\frac{n}{2}$

That $n-p(n)<n$ follows rather trivially from the fact that prime numbers exist, so that is really not an interesting bound.

In the below paper, it is proved that there exists $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that, for all $n>n_0$, $$n-p(n)<n^{0.525}.$$

Baker, R.C., Harman, G. and Pintz, J. (2001), The Difference Between Consecutive Primes, II. Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, 83: 532-562. https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/83.3.532

